# OnClick doesn't work with Friendly URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a problem. I've got a button with an OnClick handler like `protected void button_click(....)`. The syntax is OK, but it doesn't work. When I use PostBackUrl, it works. The code in `global.asax` is:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("/***/" + result + "/(\\w+)*");
match = reg.Match(url, 0);

if (match.Groups[1].Success)
{
    s_table = result;
    s_id = match.Groups[1].Value;
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/other/***.aspx?id=" + s_id.ToLower() + "&table=" + s_table.ToLower() + "content");
    return;
}
```

When I click on a button with this code wired up, nothing happens. If I delete this code, the button works.

Button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="button_click"/>
```

Thank you, MS

Comment: What does "not working" and "works" mean in this context?

Comment: OnClick doesn't work. When i click on button no reaction. The button is not in <asp:UpdatePanel>..

Comment: add `autopostback= true` and then try

Comment: I can't use autopostback in button, or I don't know how:)

Answer (score 0):

Your event function should have the correct parameter list , see here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx

Comment: Did you try to create the event in the way described in the link?

Comment: Yes, all buttons with OnClick dont work now... When I delete "Context.RewritePath(Context.Request.RawUrl, "", "", true)" OnClick works.

Comment: HALELUJA:     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            form1.Action = Request.RawUrl; <- this is the fix :))
    }

Comment: So you needed to have the correct parameter list for the method, as described in the URL I gave you.